# Simplesaml SSO silverstripe

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, silverstripe, saml-2.0

just wondering if there is any module available that is implementing simplesamlphp as a SSO library that is getting used in Silverstripe?

Cheers
RD

Answer (score 0):

The Shibboleth Module implements simplesamlphp: 
https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-shibboleth

It appears this module is for Silverstripe 2.4 and not the latest version Silverstripe 3.0.